# Can't return an Xml.Nodelist object?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, asmx

I am trying to return a list of matching XML nodes, which I was hoping to use client side i.e iterate through and display, but I get the following error when I try to return the Nodelist object:

> *To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have
>   an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their
>   inheritance hierarchy. System.Xml.XmlNodeList does not implement
>   Add(System.Object).*

The Code:

```
Private Function getAllPlayList(ByVal userID As String) As System.Xml.XmlNodeList
    Dim list As System.Xml.XmlNodeList
    Dim xPath As String = "//*[starts-with(@ID, 'B00')]"
    list = xmlDataPlaylists.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xPath)
    Return list
End Function

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetPlaylists(ByVal userID As String) As System.Xml.XmlNodeList
    Return getAllPlayList(userID)
End Function
```

The Xml I am trying to return matching nodes from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Playlists>
    <Playlist ID="B00237185@studentmail.uws.ac.uk+POP">
        <Song name="Test Song">
            <Album>Test Album 1</Album>
            <Artist>Test Artist 1</Artist>
            <Title>Test Song 1</Title> 
            <Favourite>False</Favourite>
        </Song>
        <Song name="Test Song 2">
            <Album>Test Album 2</Album>
            <Artist>Test Artist 2</Artist>
            <Title>Test Song 2</Title> 
            <Favourite>False</Favourite>
        </Song>     
    </Playlist> 
        <Playlist ID="B00237185@studentmail.uws.ac.uk+ROCK">
        <Song name="Test Song">
            <Album>Rock Album 1</Album>
            <Artist>Rock Artist 1</Artist>
            <Title>Rock Song 1</Title> 
            <Favourite>False</Favourite>
        </Song>
        <Song name="Test Song 2">
            <Album>Rock Album 2</Album>
            <Artist>Rock Artist 2</Artist>
            <Title>Rock Song 2</Title> 
            <Favourite>False</Favourite>
        </Song>     
    </Playlist>
    <Playlist ID="B00162755@studentmail.uws.ac.uk+POP">
        <Song name="Test Song">
            <Album>Test Album</Album>
            <Artist>Test Artist</Artist>
            <Title>Test Song</Title> 
            <Favourite>False</Favourite>
        </Song>
    </Playlist>
</Playlists>
```

I can return individual nodes easily enough, but when I try to return the list I get the error mentioned

Comment: First of all, ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Second, what's your question? Clearly, you can't do what you want to do. Try using LINQ to XML.